# Equivalent definitions of a local algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings

Let $A$ be a unital, associative commutative algebra over a field $k$.
In particular, $A$ is a ring and we call $A$ *local* if it is local as a ring. Namely, call $A$ local if $A$ has a unique maximal ideal.

I have encountered the following different definition of a *local algebra*: $A$ is called local if it is finite-dimensional as a $k$-algebra and if $A/J(A)\cong k$. Here $J(A)$ denotes the Jacobson radical of $A$.

Are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: Perhaps heuristically if $A$ is a ring rather than an algebra, if it is local there is a unique maximal idea $m$, so $J(A)=m$, and theen $A/J(A)$ will be a field (and I'm sure it probably isn't hard to show it is $k$). Then if $A/J(A)\cong k$, then that implies that $J(A)$ must be a maximal ideal, but as $J(A)$ is the intersection of all maximal ideals, that implies there must be a unique maximal ideal, so $A$ has a unique maximal ideal and is local. I know this is just for the case where $A$ is a ring but I'm sure you can extend this idea for the algebra case.

Comment: The first definition, in the commutative case, allows for ring of formal series $k((t))$ which is not finite-dimensional over $k.$

Comment: It looks like you are assuming commutativity? If so, you should mention it in the body or use the [commutative-algebra] tag

Comment: @StevenCreech There isn't any reason to expect $A/J(A)$ is $k$. You could have, for example, $A=\mathbb C$ and $k=\mathbb R$.

Comment: You are correct, as I said I was just giving a heuristic for why you might expect these to be the same definition of course I did not give a proof (or use the finite-dimensional over $k$), so clearly mine is not entirely correct which is why I left it as a comment over an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using these definitions given

1. There exists an algebra satisfying the first definition, but failing to satisfy the finite dimensionality criterion of the second: $A=\mathbb R$ and $k=\mathbb Q$.
2. There exists an algebra satisfying the first definition, and the finite dimensionality condition, but not the isomorphism in the second condition:
   $A=\mathbb C$ and $k=\mathbb R$.

These can be tweaked, of course, so that $A$ isn't just a field.

What's true in general is that (for a commutative ring) $R/J(R)$ is a field iff $R$ has a unique maximal ideal.  But if $R$ is a $k$ algebra, the field $R/J(R)$ can be quite different from $k$.  So, you can see the second definition is defining something much more special than an algebra that's simply a local ring.